# Tiled2Unity not accepting a .txm file

Tags: unity, tiled, tiled2unity

I'm trying to import a map from Tiled to Unity. I have seen on several video tutorials (all of them on Windows) that they used Tiled2Unity in order to import such files. However, when I download Tiled2Unity, it does not accept .tmx files. It says that it wants .xml. Fair enough--I export it from Tiled as an .xml, and then it can't read the file.

Has anyone else had this problem? Anyone know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone was as silly as I was, you have to "Open" the .txm file via the top menus and you can ignore the XML option.